# How can I add relative path to a pdf file link in drupal menu

Tags: routes

I have created menu link for a pdf file. I can use a full path like "http://website/sites/all/myfiles/file.pdf", but if I try to put a relative link such as "sites/all/myfiles/file.pdf" it does not work. If anyone has idea please tell me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing with the menu system is that what you are typing is not a relative path, but an internal Drupal URL.

Since what you are after is not a Drupal path, but instead a static file server outside of Drupal by your webserver your options are limited.

- You can write the full url like you tried yourself
- You can create a module/theme where you can make this possible, either by adding the extra link or creating a drupal path that redirects to the static file.

Of these, I personally think that a an absolute path is the lessor of evils, unless you need to do this a lot of times.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the [Menu Token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token) module. Copy your absolute PDF url to your path textfield and replace the servername with [site:url]. Also make sure the uses tokens checkbox is activated and save your menu item... In combination with the [Menu Attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module you could even link your PDF's to a blank browser tab/window if you like so.

Comment: This works great, except on my Drupal 6 installation I had to use `[site-url]` rather than `[site:url]`.  I have Menu Token 6.x-1.0-alpha2+0-dev and Token 6.x-1.19 installed.

Answer (score 4):

Drupal uses "clean URLs" so when you're on the `node/123` page and you are visualizing a link such as:

```
<a href="sites/all/myfiles/file.pdf">PDF file</a>
```

Your browser will interpret it as "node/123/sites/all/myfiles/file.pdf" which won't work. You have to put a "/" at the beginning of the URL:

```
<a href="/sites/all/myfiles/file.pdf">PDF file</a>
```

Of course, if your site is in a subdirectory, you need to append it; the safest way is to use [`l()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/7):

```
<?php echo l('PDF file', 'sites/all/myfiles/file.pdf'); ?>
```

**Edit Dic, 18:** use `l()` as per kiamlaluno advice.

Comment: The correct way is to output a Drupal URL is to use `url()`; the function always output the correct URL, independently from Drupal using clean URLs (or not), or Drupal being installed in a sub-directory of the server root directory (or not). Actually, in such cases you should use `l()`, which outputs the `<a>` tag for a Drupal URL.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure you could use `l()` without a Drupal internal path ;)

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new content type (e.g. "file download")
- Give it a field URL (a link, or a regular text field)
- Override the template file used in your theme (e.g. node--file-download.tpl.php)
- In this file, put the PHP code to load the field with the URL of file, and then put the following code:

  ```
  Header("Location: file_address");
  ```
- Create a pattern in the Pathauto module for this kind of content type (e.g. "file/download/name" or "download/file_id")
- Then, you can put it in the menu without problems

I bet there's an easier way, but this should also do the work. It should be double considered in a matter of security.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I also used like
Create new content

And add a code any of following

<?php
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header("Location: sites/all/myfiles/file.pdf");
?>

OR
<script type="text/javascript">   
 window.open('sites/all/myfiles/File.pdf','MyFile','width=400,height=350'); 
</script> 

I just used menu link to the content and this content redirects to my pdf file.
but I have about 100s of pdf. For which I need to create 100s of contents. So I am searchinhg for any other solution which is easy and safety for my site.

Comment: So maybe use module Pages? Try creating: 
path : http://localhost:8888/drupal/download_file/%file_name
variant_type :  http response.
and limit it to folder with those 100 files.. This seems to be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [Pathologic](http://drupal.org/project/pathologic) module, and your relative links will work just fine.

Comment: Pathlogic only works on node content as a filter.  It would not work for menu items

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Menu HTML](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_html) module together with **Special Menu Items** module
. This will allow you to place anchor pointing to you file as Menu link title, and **nolink** tag as menu path.

Just take a look at the screenshot:

[image: File path as menu item]