# Use a managed file in a menu_item

Tags: 7, routes, files

Is there a way to create a menu that links to a managed file? I tried many times, but nothing I tried works.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Managed file is new to me but looks interesting. Is this what you're referencing? http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file ?

Answer (score 1):

If you enter the full path of the file, it should work but if you're looking to create the menu with a relative path, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335700/drupal-primary-link-item-to-a-relative-file-on-the-server or [How can I add relative path to a pdf file link in drupal menu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17383/how-can-i-add-relative-path-to-a-pdf-file-link-in-drupal-menu)

Comment: Webfm doesn't have a version for drupal 7, is there any similar solution for Drupal 7?